# Using a loop to set multiple timeouts for a function

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, momentjs

I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle time. 10 Inning objects **(durations)** have properly been defined with start and end times, as shown in [this question's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmuX6/9/).

This script is meant to use the the **[difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)** between an Inning **end** time and the **present** to define the necessary `Timeout` to be set for a function `endInning()` to be called. This is implemented within a loop to handle the 10 Innings.

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { // for each of ten defined innings

    // calculate the difference between the end of inning x and now
    timeTillEnd = moment(Game.innings[x].start).diff(moment(now),"milliseconds");

    // and set the necessary delay
    setTimeout(function () { 
        endInning(x);
    }, timeTillEnd);

}
```

However, instead of resulting in delays that increment by 12 hours, each delay is the same.

---

The result:

- Ending **Inning 1** on **Friday**, 12:00 PM, **412712000** ms from **now**.
- Ending **Inning 2** on **Friday**, 12:00 PM, **412712000** ms from **now**.
- Ending **Inning 3** on **Friday**, 12:00 PM, **412712000** ms from **now**.
- ...and so on, until Inning 10.

---

**What's my mistake and how can I fix it?**

---

Edits:

After asking questions related to my practices with this script, I think that these questions / answers are related:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Why shouldn't I make functions within a loop in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799139/why-shouldnt-i-make-functions-within-a-loop-in-javascript)

**So my question becomes:** How can I apply [this practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) to my specific situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual problem with ending dates does not belong to timeouts (however, that's *still a problem* with them)

**first** - you created one `inning` object while you need to create 10

so, move

```
var inning = new Object();
```

inside the first `for` loop, this way you will create 10 inning objects instead of one.

**second** - you misused `moment` library object

```
inning.start = beginning.moment.add("hours", (inningHours * x)); //WRONG
```

you just **modified beginning.moment** variable which is not what you trying to achieve!

In javascript, **all objects are passed by references** https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880456/870183

So, you must create new moment object and then modify it.

```
inning.start = moment(beginning.moment).add("hours", (inningHours * x)); //correct
```

**third** - timeout problem. For every timeout we need to create another function with another x variable

Closures was hard to understand for me, so keep trying. https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/870183

Let's create a function which will return another function

```
function endInningFunc(x){
    return function () {
        endInning(x)
    }
}
```

and then we will pass new function **where x will be "locked" to its value** to `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(endInningFunc(x), timeTillEnd);
```

last thing, don't use global variables! http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

for example, `for (var x=0);`

finally, the working example. http://jsfiddle.net/LmuX6/13/

Comment: Akshay's answer provided the necessary information, but this one provides that with much additional help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { alert(i); }, 100);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
  doSetTimeout(i);
}
```

copied it from [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value)
I won't use it if I am looping too much as every function call is creating a new function object and it will be memory intensive if you are looping too much, alternative would be to create a class like structure.
example http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

```
function Inning(x) {
    this.x= x;
}

Inning.prototype.onTimeOut = function() {
    // do your thing with this.x
};
```