# How does angular or js return data without specifying a parameter name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The title doesnt really explain what i am trying to ask here. Well here is an example:

```
.factory('Story', function($http) {
   var storyFactory = {};
   Factory.getStory = function() {
      return $http.get('/api');
   }
})


.controller('StoryController', function(story) {

var vm = this;

Story.allStory()
    .sucess(function(mydata) {

    })
})
```

So how allStory() returns data into mydata?

Comment: Please explain your problem more precisely

Comment: in your code not declaring `allStory`. Are you sure that post all needed code?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, via Dependency Injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: methinks you need see this question: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: suvroc, How AllStory() return data into mydata so that inside .sucess i was able to use data that is return from AllStory().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about the way javascript replaces the written code with the logical object at the time?

eg.

```
console.log(new Array({"getWalkDetails":function(){return {"MaxSpeed":15, "DistanceWalked": 123}} },
                       "walking on sunshine", 
                       "oh oh" ).shift().getWalkDetails().MaxSpeed);
//outputs "15" to the console
```

This can be rewritten as

```
var arr = new Array();
var func = function(){
        var details = new Object();
        details.MaxSpeed =15;
        details.DistanceWalked = 124;
        return details;
}
var obj = {"getWalkDetails" : func};
arr.push(obj);
arr.push("walking on sunshine");
arr.push("oh oh");

var firstItem = arr.shift();
//the array function 'shift()' is used to remove the first item in the array and return it to the variable
var walkingDetails = firstItem.getWalkingDetails()//same as func() or obj.getWalkingDetails()
console.log(walkingDetails.MaxSpeed);//15
```

As you can see we stored most of the the interpreted outputs as variables to be used seperately.

**EDIT:**
If you are asking how to pass objects by reference in javascript to allow the mydata variable to receive any changes done to it in the function it is passed to. then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference) might be helpful to you:
[javascript pass object as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference)

**EDIT:** 
edited the code above a bit more

Comment: Thanks that explains it. Javascript is much harder to understand the syntax than any other language

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure either what you mean (especially because I never worked with Angular), but I have a feeling you're puzzled by this little trick:

```
//+ fn -> [a]
var getParameterNames = (function () {
    var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg,
        ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;

    return function (fn) {
        var fnStr = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, ''),
            names = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);

        return names || [];
    };
})();

function add (x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

console.log(getParameterNames(add));    // => ['x', 'y']
```

Edit: And [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3azLczj/).