# Array always get last value in each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my loop I create a new variable and set a new value each time its looping(obviously)

But when the loop is done and outside my loop I `console.log()` the array which  is filled in the loop. Its logging every element with the value of the last element.

I've tried to use `.push()` to fill the array.

```
state = {
    dates: ['2019-02-04', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-06'],
    entry: {
        value1: undefined,
        value2: undefined,
        value3: {
            value3_1: undefined,
            value3_2: undefined
        },
        date: undefined
    }
}

functionToFillArray() {
    let entries = [],
        entry = this.state.entry;

        entry.value1 = 'value1';
        entry.value2 = 'value2';
        entry.value3 = {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        };

    this.state.dates.forEach((date, i) => {
        entry.date = date;

        entries.push(entry);
    });

    console.log(entries);
}
```

The output that I would expect is:

```
[
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-04'
    },
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-05'
    },
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-06'
    }
]
```

The value I get(Always the same date):

```
[
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-06'
    },
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-06'
    },
    {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: {
            value3_1: 'value3_1',
            value3_2: 'value3_2'
        },
        date: '2019-02-06'
    }
]
```

Comment: In JavaScript objects are always passed by copy-reference. You are always updating `this.state.entry` and not a new object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript pass object as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Your code mutates the same `this.state.entry` object in each iteration and pushes that *single* object reference again and again to the array, so in the end that array indeed contains several entries, but all having the same object reference.

All in all, the `this.state.entry` value -- which you seem to want to use like a template -- really serves no purpose. You anyway are assigning new values to *all* of its properties. So there seems no need for it.

Just replace this:

```
let entry = this.state.entry;
```

with:

```
let entry = {};
```

Now `entry` will be a *newly* created object in each iteration.

#### Updated Question - Updated Answer

After the edit to your question, you only assign a `date` property to the *same* object over and over again.

The principle remains the same. Now replace this:

```
functionToFillArray() {
    let entries = [],
        entry = this.state.entry;
    entry.value1 = 'value1';
    entry.value2 = 'value2';
    entry.value3 = {
        value3_1: 'value3_1',
        value3_2: 'value3_2'
    };
    this.state.dates.forEach((date, i) => {
        entry.date = date;
        entries.push(entry);
    });
    console.log(entries);
}
```

...with:

```
functionToFillArray() {
    let entries = this.state.dates.map((date, i) => {
        return {
            value1: 'value1',
            value2: 'value2',
            value3: {
                value3_1: 'value3_1',
                value3_2: 'value3_2'
            },
            date
        };
    });
    console.log(entries);
}
```

This way you create a new object in each iteration. There is no gain to first initialise an object and then overwrite each of its properties, as then you still are working with a single object. You need a new one each iteration.

Note that the Array's `map` method is more useful here than `forEach`, but it is not related to your problem.

Comment: But in this case I have to copy the whole object and define the properties again.

Comment: But you are doing that already (i.e. you are already defining the properties again) -- which is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my example code. I displayed the way I tried as first later on I tried it like the update example

Comment: I added a section to my answer to answer your modified question.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring.

```js
const state = {
  dates: ['2019-02-04', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-06'],
  entry: {
    value1: undefined,
    value2: undefined,
    value3: {
      value3_1: undefined,
      value3_2: undefined
    },
    date: undefined
  }
};

function ToFillArray() {
  let entries = [];

  state.dates.forEach((date, i) => {
    const entry = {
      ...state.entry,
      value1: 'value1',
      value2: 'value2',
      value3: {
        value3_1: 'value3_1',
        value3_2: 'value3_2'
      },
      date
    };

    entries.push(entry);
  });

  console.log(entries);
}

ToFillArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a copy, you are creating a link to this.state.entry and after that creating circular objects.
Try creating a copy first.

```
...
this.state.dates.forEach((date, i) => {
        let entry = {...this.state.entry};
...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are always referring to the same variable instead of copying it, modifying the state, try this instead:

```
let stateCopy= {...this.state};
let entry = stateCopy.entry

    entry.value1 = 'value1';
    entry.value2 = 'value2';
    entry.value3 = {
        value3_1: 'value3_1',
        value3_2: 'value3_2'
    };
    entry.date = date;

    entries.push(entry);
```

You can refer to [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5) for a more detailed explanation :)

Also in this particular case it's not really necessary to re-use the object in the state since you assign the properties each time

Comment: Why? Should not be a copy?

Comment: Sure, but the copy of `state` is shallow, so `entry` will still reference the *same* object.