# Why javascript object value is changed?

Tags: javascript, object

Can anyone explain to me why the output value is changed to "20, 2" instead of the original "1, 2"?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <script>
    var x = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
    var y = x;
    y.a = 20;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.a;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x.b;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS passes objects by reference, there are some in depth questions relating to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference

Comment: Since you seem to be new to JavaScript, I highly suggest *not* using `var` as it is considered bad practice. You should use `let` or `const`.

Comment: @Seblor I would argue that there's nothing wrong with using `var` in front end JS, in fact if you're aiming for a good range of browser support, we're still (unfortunately) on the border of having to avoid using let/const at all.

Comment: @DBS While I understand what you mean, I really think the use of `var` and the browser support should be left to the transpilers (like Babel). If people keep using `var`, they will have a hard time changing later on. Also using the newer ECMAScript versions usually improves the code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing `y` to the reference of `x` which itself is pointing to the object `{a:1,b:2}`.

So in memory it is:

```
x --> {a:1,b:2}
```

After you do `y = x`, it becomes:

```
y --> x --> {a:1,b:2}
```

Or to put it simply:

```
x --> {a:20,b:2}
         ^
         |
y -------
```

Now when you do `y.a = 20`, since `y` and `x` are both pointing to the same object when properties of the object is changed through either of the references `x` or `y` the change will be reflected in both the references:

```
y --> {a:20,b:2}
        ^
        |
x -------
```

That is why you get `20,2` when you get `x.a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var y=x
```

In the above line `y` is passed the reference of `x` instead of the whole object x. Any changes made to the object will get reflected in all the variables containing the reference of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Because its the same `reference` (same address for memory location where the object is stored) both x and y are now the same reference so changing one will change the value stored, and now as they are the same reference they will output the same object values.

I would add something extra to make this answer more productive.

> Shallow -Copy
>
> Shallow copy is a bit-wise copy of an object. A new object is created
>   that has an exact copy of the values in the original object. If any of
>   the fields of the object are references to other objects, just the
>   reference addresses are copied i.e., only the memory address is
>   copied.

example

```
let x={"a":1,"b":2};
let y=x;  //It makes a copy of the reference to x into y
```

So, the addresses of x and y will be the same i.e. they will be pointing to the same memory location.
so if you do this

```
y.a=9;
```

and now when you print y on the screen

```
console.log(y) // it prints {"a":9,"b":2};
```

but the interesting fact here is , when you print x

```
console.log(x)  // it also prints {"a":9,"b":2};
```

So Now how to change this scenario??. The solution is a deep copy

> Deep copy
>
> A deep copy copies all fields and makes copies of dynamically
>   allocated memory pointed to by the fields. A deep copy occurs when an
>   object is copied along with the objects to which it refers.

in Lehman terms you create a variable y allocate it a different memory location, copy all the members of x, assign the copied members to y

the easiest way to do it is by `stringifying` the object

```
let y=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))
```

now if we do

```
y.a=9
```

and print y

```
console.log(y) // it prints {"a":9,"b":2};
```

and if we print x

```
console.log(x) //  it prints {"a":1,"b":2};
```

```js
/// shallow copy

let x = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
};
let y = x;
y.a = 9;
console.log(y);
console.log(x);


// Deep Copy

let z = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
};
let t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(z));
t.a = 9;
console.log("z:", z);
console.log("t:", t);
```

This scenario becomes more fun when we have nested objects

```js
let c = {
  "a": {
    "A": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "B": 2
  }
};
let t = Object.assign({}, c); // It is also shallow copying
t.a.A = "7"; // since a is a nested object so again reference is passed
console.log(c);
console.log(t)
console.log("Second Scenario-------------------")


let d = {
  "a": {
    "A": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "B": 2
  }
};
let k = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d));
k.a.A = 88
console.log(d)
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `y` & `x` both point to same memory location.If you want a separate copy , then deep copy the object. `JSON.parse` & `JSON.stringify`

```js
var x = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
y.a = 20;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.a;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x.b;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```