# JS passing the whole object to a function takes more memory

Tags: javascript

Today I learned that if for example I have an object:

```
var foo = {a: 1, b: { ... }}
```

And I pass it to a function:

```
function test(foo) {
  foo.b
}
```

It has to load the whole `foo` object into the function’s scope to access
the `b` property, which increases the memory consumption.

The advice in the book is to always pass only what you need instead:

```
function test(b) {
   b
 }

 test(foo.b)
```

My question if that's is true? and why? the object is passed by reference.

Comment: While passing an object into a function a variable created that references the passed object not the objects address itself. So in a function  if you assign it sth like this `foo = {}` it won't effect the passed object you only changed the reference of the scoped variable.

Comment: But I can mutate the object properties.

Comment: Yes because your variable points to original object. So you have 2 variables `foo` which is original and the one generated for function that points to original

Comment: And both points to the same address in memory

Comment: That is because it will create a new environment record for the function scope which pretty much copies over the values. Reference: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records

Comment: @scripton but the record is more or less equal in both cases. Also the spec does not mandate a memory model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880418/javascript-pass-object-as-reference, duplicated reference of same object is passed, so you can mutate the object but not replace it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It has to load the whole foo object into the function’s scope to access the b property, which increases the memory consumption.

This is just *wrong*. As you said

> the object is passed by reference.

Thus in both cases a reference gets passed, which will consume the same memory (if it does at all).

> The advice in the book is to always pass only what you need instead

That makes sense as a good practice for clean design.

Answer (score 2):

Nope and here's proof.

```
const foo = {a: 1, b: 'bar'}

function printB(obj){
    console.log(obj.b)
    setTimeout(() =>console.log(obj.b),1000)
}

// pitfall changing a object inside a function
function editB(obj){
    obj.b = `I'm just writing something to an object`
}

printB(foo)
// prints bar
editB(foo)
// after one second it prints 'I'm just writing something to an object'
```

Comment: watch out for editing an object inside a function because it WILL impact other functions using this object --> Eliminated by passing a value so its clearly the better option